# Insert ad code after n partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

Rails 4.2

I have a collection displaying from a partial - is there a way to add a fragment of code in after a certain number in the collection?

So I have a 10 blog posts being shown in a list, each post's formatting from the partial list. I'd like to insert my AdSense code after every 3 posts

```
<%= render partial: "list", collection: @posts %>
```

Is there a way to do that automatically, or would I have to do something like assign a numbered id to each post and have "if (id/3) % 1 == 0", and conditionally display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well inside the partial `_list.html.erb`, you can do check the counter variable provided by Rails `list_iteration`. So your check will be inside the `_list.html.erb` partial as:

```
render 'ad' if list_iteration.index % 3 == 0
```

You can also use `list_counter` helper.

Read this [Rendering a collection of partials](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

```
<%= render partial: "ad", collection: @advertisements %>
```

> This will render `“advertiser/_ad.html.erb”` and pass the local variable ad to the template for display. ***An iteration object will automatically be made available to the template with a name of the form partial_name_iteration***. The iteration object has knowledge about which index the current object has in the collection and the total size of the collection. The iteration object also has two convenience methods, `first?` and `last?`. In the case of the example above, the template would be `fed ad_iteration`. For backwards compatibility the `partial_name_counter` is still present and is mapped to the iteration's `index` method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<% @posts.each_slice(3) do |posts| %>
   <%= render partial: "list", collection: posts %>
   <%= render partial: 'ad_sense' %>
<% end %>
```

Might work

[each_slice docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) for further reading

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with the loop index like

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <%= render partial: 'list', locals:{post: post} %>
  <% if index % 3 == 2 %>
     #adsense code here
  <% end %>
<%end %>
```